# Trigger J2ME application when GPS coordinates change

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps, coordinates, java-me

I need to know, how to trigger or open J2ME application when GPS coordinates changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that starting an application based on GPS co-ordinate chnages is possible generically on J2ME. Why not have your application running all the time, monitoring the GPS co-ordinates and then take action when you detect a significant change?

Comment: i think it will consume battery power

Comment: You'd need GPS always-on to achieve what you want anyway, that will consume a lot of battery power.

GPS co-ordinates fluctuate slightly on every location update anyway, I assume you actually meant "open the app when GPS co-ordinates change by a certain minimum amount".  In which case why not use a more coarse granularity location measurement, such as cell ID.  This will use less battery power.  Still, all you can do is bring the app from background to foreground, this will only work in MIDP environments supporting background apps such as Series 60.

Comment: i like your idea but i never found CELLID Database for india

Comment: already i tried opencellid.org but lots of cellid to be created for India. i think google have the best CELLID database but they are not allow users to acccess dataase.